# Can't insert new rows to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Here is my php:

```
<?php
require included.php; //which contains the function getpost($post_id)
//once I use the getpost() function below to return a string which is the post 
//content, then I can not insert this new row to database.if I change it something 
//like $post_content='this is the post content' , it would insert a row to database

$post_content=getpost($post_id);
if($insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `join` VALUES('','username','$post_content')"))
{
   echo 'ok';
}
else{

   echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Here is the function `getpost($post_id)` in the included.php:

```
function getpost($post_id){

    $select_post=mysql_query("SELECT `post_text` FROM `user_post` WHERE `id`='$post_id' ");
return mysql_result($select_post,0,'post_text');
}
```

those data would be sent back to jquery AJAX request as data, and if I echo the `$post_content = get_post($post_id)`, I can alert the right stuffs, it seems something wrong to use a function to get the post content then it can't be inserted into the database.

Comment: Remove the "R" in `'VALUERS'`, for one thing.  And why would you name a table "join".  That is a SQL keyword and will make for rather confusing looking queries.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword for INSERT is `VALUES` not `VALUERS`:

```
if($insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `join` VALUERS('','username','$post_content')"))
```

Should be

```
if($insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `join` VALUES ('','username','$post_content')"))
```

If you had error checking in place, like using `mysql_error()` you would have caught this quickly.

Also, [please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I typed wrong in my question, if I use $post_content='hello, wolrd', to assign value to the $post_content, the query would insert a row successfully

Answer (score 0):

Typo -

```
...INSERT INTO `join` VALUERS('','usern...
                           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you have a typo?
INSERT INTO `join` VALUERS('','username','$post_content') should be
INSERT INTO `join` VALUES('','username','$post_content')
I can't see anything else wrong

Comment: yes,I typed it wrong in my question, if I use $post_content='hello, wolrd', to assign value to the $post_content, the query would insert a row successfully, but if I use the function getpost() to return content and assign to the $post_content,it won;t work